# Converting Word2Vec embedding in C to Python's Gensim Word2vec

Tags: python, c, tensorflow, word2vec, gensim

Using https://github.com/dav/word2vec, I have built Word2Vec embedding. I have to use that output in Python's Gensim's Word2Vec.

I have VectorsFile.txt and VocabuloryFile.txt for my Corpus.txt.

How to do that ..

Can you please .. ?

Comment: Could you add an example of your vectorsFile?

Comment: In Gensim, I found  at 

 https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html. 

`code
>>> from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

>>> word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.txt', binary=False)  # C text format

>>> word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.bin', binary=True)  # C binary format 
code`

This solved the problem.